# Java: Shell commands with redirection

Tags: java, shell, ubuntu, io-redirection

I am trying to execute redirection in shell using java, but I am getting an empty `file1.txt` for the command: `ls -all > file1.txt`. 
Although `ls -all` is executed properly.

`commandLine` is of type String and has the command that I would want to execute. 
 for example `String commandLine = "ls -all";`

Code Snippet(This is the relevant section of the code) :

```
   StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
   Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    Process process = runtime.exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", commandLine});
    process.waitFor();

    try {
         BufferedReader reader = 
           new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));

          String line;          
          line = "";
          while ((line = reader.readLine())!= null) {
              output.append(line);
              output.append("\n");
          }
    } 
    catch(Exception ex) {
      ex.printStackTrace();
    } 
    finally {
      process.destroy();
    }
```

Finally I am processing the output from the instance `output`.
Also, I want to execute the command similar to `curl -v http://www.centos.org > /dev/null` but this gives me an empty response too !

Comment: what is `commandLine`?

Comment: Oops forgot to mention that. I have edited my question to include what commandLine is !
Thanks for bringing that up !

Comment: > /dev/null will obviously give you an empty response, as that's the reason people redirect to /dev/null

Comment: But running the same command on bash gives me an output. what should I have instead of /dev/null to get an output ?
Also, why is file1.txt empty

Comment: maybe an error you mean? don't mix stdout with stderr!

Comment: I meant stderr !
What about file1.txt ?

Comment: depending on your os `/bin/sh` and `/bin/bash` may behave differently, try changing `Process process = runtime.exec(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", commandLine});` to `Process process = runtime.exec(new String[]{"/bin/bash", "-c", commandLine});`

Comment: How do you know `ls -all` worked fine? Maybe you are trying to exec a 6-character command including a space and a hyphen without any options. The stderr will not be shown in file1.txt.

Comment: Both `ls -al` and `curl` can be done in Java without using any external programs.  In my opinion, that would be cleaner than dealing with the output of another process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Short answer

You are reading `stdout`, which is empty because you redirected `stdout` to `/dev/null`. Use `getErrorStream()` instead of `getInputStream()` to get `stderr`.

### `stdout` and `stderr`

There are 2 output streams of every process, `stdout` and `stderr`. In the case of the mentioned `curl -v http://www.centos.org`, the 2 output streams would be the following streams:

`stdout`:

```
<html>
<head><title>301 Moved Permanently</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>301 Moved Permanently</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.6.3</center>
</body>
</html>
```

`stderr`:

```
* Rebuilt URL to: http://www.centos.org/
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0*   Trying 85.12.30.226...
* Connected to www.centos.org (85.12.30.226) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: www.centos.org
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
< Server: nginx/1.6.3
< Date: Thu, 19 May 2016 15:31:03 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Content-Length: 184
< Connection: keep-alive
< Location: https://www.centos.org/
< 
{ [184 bytes data]
100   184  100   184    0     0   1184      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1187
* Connection #0 to host www.centos.org left intact
```

The `>` operator will redirect only `stdout`, but `stderr` will be untouched.

### Execution in the terminal

In terminals you usually see `stdout` and `stderr` mixed. So if you execute `curl -v http://www.centos.org > /dev/null`, then `stdout` will be redirected to `/dev/null`, but you will still see the output of `stderr`. That's what you observe, when you say that "*running the same command on bash gives [...] an output.*"

### Execution from Java

Execution of a command from Java, on the other hand, will keep the two streams separated. The stream `stdout` can be obtained using `process.getInputStream()`, and `stderr` can be obtained using `process.getErrorStream()`.

You are using the former (`stdout`), but since `stdout` is redirected to `/dev/null` in your example (`curl -v http://www.centos.org`), it doesn't come as a surprise that you don't see any output.

The only output you could obtain would be `stderr`. For that you would have to replace `process.getInputStream()` by `process.getErrorStream()`.

### Empty `file1.txt`

You are stating in the comments that the file `file1.txt` is empty after executing some command like this `ls -all > file1.txt` from Java.

The most likely reason for this is that the execution of `ls` actually failed, but you don't see the error message because it is printed to `stderr` - which you never read. You state that the same command works fine in the terminal, but execution environments are different (different environment variables, different working directory, etc.), which can make the same command fail. So read `stderr` to get the error message.

Another possible reason for an empty `file1.txt` is that you check a different file because the working directory is unknown to you. Happened to me more than once that I checked the wrong file! Check the timestamp to make sure that it's the correct file.

Comment: Thank you,
at that time I did not fully understand iostreams and /dev/null.